# Register BroadcastReceiver only during process lifecycle

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

I have come across this design problem. I have an app that displays a list of mp3 the user can just play online or download to play locally. Now I want to add to the list view row layout a green tick in case the file has been downloaded. For this purpose, in the model class I have added a field called `isDownloaded()`, which is initialized when a loader class loads from an xml file the mp3 list, then checks if they exist in the file system and sets the `isDownloaded()`value accordingly. The data is downloaded once, when the app process starts, and it keeps it during config changes to not reload it. Now here it comes the problem: I download the files with the system download manager which fires an intent when the file finishes downloading. To update the listview, I register a BroadcastReceiver during `onStart()` and unregister it during `onStop()`, so in case the download finishes while the user activity is in the foreground, the listview is updated. But what if the activity is in the background and the process has not been destroyed? The downloading finished intent is lost and when the user gets back to the activity the UI wont be updated as the model has not been updated. It is obvious I need something else, so when the user is not interacting with the activity the model gets updated and when the user comes back the activity will repaint the listview during `onStart()`. Registering a BroadcastReceiver in the manifest doesnt seem to be a solution, because if the process has been already killed when the downloading finish, it is not needed to start the process again and update the model (which obviously wouldnt be even loaded). I would appreciate any design ideas or advices, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is registering the BroadcastReceiver in the application class during `onCreate()` using the application context. This way the BroadcastReceiver is active as long as the app process is alive.

Answer (score 0):

Would simply moving register/unregister to onCreate and onDestroy not work?

Alternatively, if it was me,  I would keep some sort of meta file or database that keeps track of whether the mp3 has been downloaded. This way registering in manifest would work because the list would be updated based on the meta data,  which again could be updated independently of the activity life cycle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Registering during `onCreate()` wouldnt fix the problem, because the activity could be kill but the proccess wouldnt so you would be in the same situation. I think maintaining a database/file is kinda overkill for this simple application. The loader simply checks if file exist and sets the model when it is loaded. I need some way to update the already loaded data (remember the mp3 arraylist is loaded only once, when the loader class is created) which is shared across the whole application.